# How to stop a For...Next in Excel with button?

Tags: vba, excel

The code below was something I modified from a solution found online. The context of the form.

The form has a combo box with 3 buttons(Add, Next, Done)

- Add will paste whatever is selected from combo box
- Next is supposed to move to next empty cell in column (code below)
- Done should close the form so the spreadsheet can be viewed.(code below)

What I'm running into is that when I hit the "done" button, it doesn't close out if I've run "next". The For...Next loop goes until all spaces are filled. What I want is a way to stop the for loop when I hit "done" I've tried adding a statement to show if current cell has characters to exit for but then it just killed the code and it wouldn't run at all. So I'm at a loss right now, if anyone would be able to help that would be great. Thanks.

```
Private Sub nxtBtn_Click()

Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String, cString As String


sourceCol = 7   'column G has a value of 7
rowCount = Cells(Rows.count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it

For currentRow = 4 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
        Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub done_bn_Click()


    'Refresh the workbook/pivot tables
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'Close form
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: write `Exit For` directly below the `Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select` line

Comment: My above comment will stop the code execution once it finds the cell you want selected. Then when you click done, it will work as no code will be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a loop to find the first blank cell in column F, simply use the [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method.  You can replace your entire loop with this one line:

```
Columns("F").Find(vbNullString, Range("F3"), xlValues, xlWhole).Select
```

That way you don't have to exit code execution, because this will find the first blank cell in column F after cell F3 (which I'm guessing is a header) with no looping required.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to pause the loop and check for any events sent to the program.

In VBA, there is the function DoEvents.  This, in layman's terms, allows the program to "catch up to itself".  So, what I'd suggest is adding a DoEvents to your loop, and then check for keystrokes.  You want to trap the Ctrl/Break keys, which is what would pause VBA.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
Private Sub nxtBtn_Click()

Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String, cString As String


sourceCol = 7   'column F has a value of 7
rowCount = Cells(Rows.count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it

For currentRow = 4 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
        Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
        End If

    'Allow the code to catch up, so it can determine if Ctrl/Break were sent
    DoEvents
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub done_bn_Click()

    'Send the Ctrl/Break keys to Excel
    Application.SendKeys("^{BREAK}")

    'Refresh the workbook/pivot tables
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'Close form
    Unload Me

End Sub
```